# Can I open a pdf in cmd with a 'space' in the pdf name?

Tags: cmd

I'm trying to learn cmd and just stumbled upon this problem. I just can't seem to open a file with a space in the name.

Comment: Perhaps you can post the command you tried and the result you got?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enclosing the `"`file name in quotes`"`?

The file name has to be enclosed in "double quotes" like:

```
AcroRd32.exe "C:\path\to\filename with spaces.pdf"
```

This is assuming that `AcroRd32.exe` is in your path and is the application  you'd open a PDF file with.

Details can be found in [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html).

In fact, simply typing `"C:\path\to\filename with spaces.pdf"` could work as well since .pdf is a [known registered file extension/association](https://superuser.com/questions/362063/how-to-associate-a-file-with-a-program-in-windows-via-cmd).

There are a lot of resources on the web for learning "DOS Command Line Basics", using the "command line interpreter"; you can search world wide web for them. Do not confuse with "MS-DOS programming", which is writing programs which run on the MS-DOS operating system.

PS: As a skill, far more useful would be to learn [PowerShell](https://ss64.com/ps/), the evolutionary replacement of cmd introduced in the mid 2000's rather than Windows CMD. It is more complicated, but more powerful. If you see "PS" in the prompt (as in your comment), that's PowerShell.